# How to move a splitted pane of editor window to another monitor?

Tags: visual-studio

As you know you can split an Editor window in two parts. So I can edit one part of a file and look at another of same file at same time. That is a great feature.

How can I move one part to another monitor?
Or is it possible to open the same file twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the menu item Window, select "New Window". Make sure the tab you want duplicated is selected.

The new window can be dragged on to the other monitor.

Comment: That is correct. It renames my current tab from file.cs to file.cs:1 and opens an additional window named file.cs:2. Both windows are full synchronized while editing. Great. Thank you!